# $A$ is a ring and $I$ is an ideal of $A$ with $I \neq A$. Then, are (1) and (2) equivalent?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

$A$: commutative ring with unit.

(1) $I$ is a primary ideal of $A$.

(2) If $a,b \in A$, and $ab \in I$, then there exists a positive integer $n$ such that

$a^n \in I$ or $b^n \in I$.

I notice that they are equivalent when $I$ is prime. 
So I am looking for a primary ideal which is not prime as a counterexample.

Comment: Do you need only a YES or NO answer?

Comment: @Wuestenfux Do you know the answer? You can tell me yes or no as a hint :)

Comment: What is your definition of [primary ideal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primary_ideal)?

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem ? Question which include your own work are more likely to get an answer.

Comment: I think you should have notice that (1) implies (2), and then that there is something about the converse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No these are not equivalent.  Consider:

$\ \ \ \ $ $(2)'$ $\sqrt{I}$ is prime

and check that $(2)'$ is equivalent to $(2)$.

So for a counterexample, we want a ring $R$ with an ideal $I$ such that $\sqrt{I}$ is prime but $I$ is not primary.

This has been asked about and answered many times on stackexchange, but it is a good exercise to find a counterexample for yourself.

Comment: Yes, it's really helpful. Thank you.